# Huge delay in long polling request in Winrt/WP8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient, long-polling

I am writing universal app for Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1. I need to open long polling request to get continuously updating data stream. I doing this with `HttpClient` and its working fine, except of huge delay in getting new data from stream. On WinRT this delay about 10-20 secs and on Windows Phone its about 1-2 minutes(!!!). This is unacceptable for this app and i hope there is something wrong with my code and someone can help me to fix it. Here is my code:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
{
      client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Timeout.Infinite);
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://my.site.com/");
      handler.CookieContainer.SetCookies(client.BaseAddress, cookies);

      var link = "my/link";
      using (var tokenRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, link))
      {
           tokenRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
           tokenRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Foo", "Foo");
           tokenRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Foo1", "Foo2");
           var t = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

           using (var httpResponse = t.Content)
           {
                using (var v = await httpResponse.ReadAsStreamAsync())
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(v))
                    {
                        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: How did you make sure that it's not the server causing the delay?

Comment: @usr this is google's service and its working fine in other applictions

Comment: Windows Phone has buffering activated per default on the HTTP pipeline. I wouldn't be surprised if it interfered with long-polling. The thing is, I know how to disable it when you use an `HttpWebRequest` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.allowreadstreambuffering%28v=vs.95%29.aspx ), but I'm not sure for `HttpClient`...

Comment: @kookiz how to make it right with `HttpWebRequest`? I just tried to make something similar, but request fails in response. Request going fine to the server and it's running fine too(according to Fiddler session).

Comment: @RenDishen Have you tried without Fiddler? Requests fail on Windows Phone if the certificate isn't trusted. If you use Fiddler, make sure to install the Fiddler root certificate on the phone (or the emulator)

Comment: @kookiz yes, i did. Problem is certainly is not in fiddler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is the way how i accomplished my task. It's working not perfectly, but i getting data right away, when it appearing in `InputStream`.

```
var uri = new Uri("www.example.com");
using (var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient())
{
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Cookie.ParseAdd(this.sessionCookies);
  client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("header", "value");

  var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, Windows.Web.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
  var inputStream = await response.Content.ReadAsInputStreamAsync();
  IBuffer buffer = new Buffer(10000);

  do
  {
       buffer = await inputStream.ReadAsync(buffer, buffer.Capacity, InputStreamOptions.ReadAhead);
       var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray(), 0, (int) buffer.Length);
       Debug.WriteLine(data);                        
   } while (buffer.Length > 0);
}
```